# Stormpath multipartFile

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, stormpath

I'm using Stormpath + Spring MVC.
I have a issue when I trying to send a request with files attachments.

```
public ModelAndView insert(@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile files[], @Valid @ModelAttribute("ordemServico") OrdemServico ordemServico,
                               BindingResult result, Model model) throws IOException {
```

But I got this error below...

```
2017-03-03 17:00:34,395 ERROR [qtp504672873-22] c.s.s.c.StormpathAuthenticationEntryPoint Couldn't resolve content type
com.stormpath.sdk.servlet.http.UnresolvedMediaTypeException: No MediaType could be resolved for this request (text/css,*/*;q=0.1) and the configured producesMediaTypes settings (application/json,text/html). The ContentNegotiationResolver was not able to come up with a valid MediaType.
    at com.stormpath.sdk.servlet.filter.DefaultContentNegotiationResolver.getContentType(DefaultContentNegotiationResolver.java:59)
```

And its shows a **Access Denied Error...**

How to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
Spring Security was blocking de upload...

With this configuration in my html form:

```
<form method="POST" action="XXX?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Its works for me...